# Using extended components slots fires extended components mounted function twice

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two components: 
PageLayout.vue 
Page.vue

In PageLayout.vue I have slots and importing a mixin where I have the apiCall() and where I'm storing the response data.

In Page.vue I'm extending the PageLayout.vue and attempting to use the mixin data from PageLayout.vue.

Page.vue:

```
<template>
    <PageLayout>
        <template v-slot:links>
            {{ mixinData }}
        </template>
    </PageLayout>
</template>

<script>
import PageLayout from '@/components/PageLayout'
export default {
    extends: PageLayout,
    components: {
        PageLayout
    }
}
</script>
```

PageLayout.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <slot name="links" />   
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import api from '@/mixins/api.js';
export default {
    mixins: [ api ],
    mounted() {
        this.apiCall()
    }
}
</script>
```

Now to my issue:
The mounted hook fires the apiCall() twice.

I have no clue as to why it would cause the mounted hook to fire twice.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Just remove `extends: PageLayout` from `Page`. You want `Page` to be a wrapper for `PageLayout`. You don't want it to be a `PageLayout` (that's what `extends` does: it's a way to copy all the code from one component into another, so you don't have to write it again - but it runs as if it was also written in `Page`, too). What you have now translates to: `Page` is a `PageLayout` containing a `PageLayout`. You don't want that, do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you not only extend `PageLayout` but also use it inside of `Page`.

Since `Page` extends `PageLayout`, it inherits the `mounted` call for itself. (This is what `extends` does, it subclasses a component.)  So:

- Call #1 is from the inherited `mounted` hook in `Page`.
- Call #2 is from the `mounted` hook in `PageLayout`, since it's used in the template of `Page`

Either of the following should resolve this:

- Don't extend `Page`
- Don't use `PageLayout` in the template of `Page`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sadly I forgot to mention the most important aspect of this, the usage of a mixin. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't change anything.  I updated my answer to make the explanation even clearer.